# Which would best display the following data if you wanted to display the numbers which are outliers as well as the mean?

Tags: outliers

Which would best display the following data if you wanted to display the numbers which are outliers as well as the mean?

[4, 1, 3, 10, 18, 12, 9, 4, 15, 16, 32]

Comment: Which numbers do you consider to be "outliers" and why?  What's the purpose of the display?  Who will the audience be?

Answer (score 1):

**Comment.** Here is a boxplot (from R), which shows no outliers in your data,
according to the usual boxplot rule for outliers. Ordinarily,
a boxplot shows the sample median (as the bar within the box),
but it is easy to put in an extra point to show the location of the sample mean.

```
x = c(4, 1, 3, 10, 18, 12, 9, 4, 15, 16, 32)
boxplot(x, col="skyblue2")
  points(1, mean(x), pch=19, col="red")
```

[image]

Maybe you're thinking that the maximum value 32 should be
called an 'outlier', but it isn't quite far enough from the center
of the data to qualify as an outlier according to this rule
for designating 'outliers'.

If you change 32 to 50, then the boxplot outlier rule designates
50 as an outlier.

```
y = c(4, 1, 3, 10, 18, 12, 9, 4, 15, 16, 50)
boxplot(y, col="skyblue2")
  points(1, mean(x), pch=19, col="red")
```

[image]

**Addendum.** As @whuber points out, the boxplot criterion for outliers is not the only one worth considering. The version of that criterion most commonly implemented in statistical software uses the interquartile range (IQR), the distance between the lower quartile $Q_1$ and the upper quartile $Q_3.$ Then 'outliers' are taken to be
values below $Q_1 - 1.5\,\text{IQR}$ or above
$Q_1 + 1.5\,\text{IQR}.$

Moreover, the parameter $1.5,$ called the `range` in R, 
can be *adjusted.* For example, the following R code produces a modified boxplot that shows 32 as an 'outlier'.

```
x = c(4, 1, 3, 10, 18, 12, 9, 4, 15, 16, 32)
boxplot(x, range=1.4, horizontal=T)
```

[image]

*Note:* The parameter name `range` is not to be confused with usual definition of the *range* (max minus min) of a sample.

Comment: I feel uneasy about the implicit definition of univariate "outlier" in terms of boxplots.  For instance, [Dixon's Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dixon%27s_Q_test) identifies $32$ as a high outlier (p = 0.045).  (I'm not advocating Dixon's test nor any test for that matter, but only trying to clarify that outlier identification should not be reduced to a single criterion.)

Answer (score 1):

There is no universally agreed-upon definition of an outlier, and context is key when deciding whether to treat a point as one.

However, your data is easy to display without resorting to defining any point as such. Since you have a small dataset with, I would just plot all the raw values. I've done so using the `R` code below. Note that I have added a small amount of horizontal jitter since you have two identical entries in one case. I've also added a horizontal line for the mean.

```
library(ggplot2)

dat <- data.frame(x = rep(1, 11), b = c(4, 1, 3, 10, 18, 12, 9, 4, 15, 16, 32))
m <- mean(dat$b)

ggplot(dat, aes(x, b)) + geom_jitter(width = 0.06, height = 0, size = 2) + geom_segment(aes(0.9, m, xend = 1.1, yend = m)) +
  xlim(0, 2) + xlab('') + ylab('') + theme(
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

[image]

Or alternatively you could do something like a stacked point histogram (though this is more appealing with slightly larger datasets):

```
gplot(dat, aes(b)) + geom_dotplot(binwidth=1, method='histodot') + geom_vline(xintercept = m) + 
  xlab('') + ylab('') + theme(
  axis.text.y = element_blank(),
  axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

[image]